# jQuery mobile content padding persist

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm translating a design from psd to HTML/CSS jQuery mobile I an issue for the data-role content it makes additional padding in the right so the elements with 100% widht look having the width reduced. I can show the css style and the screenshot on my galaxy s3.[image]

and this is the following style for the container that has padding: 0px also tried to force the padding to 0 by doing this :
`<div data-role="content" class="absolute_content" style="padding:0px;">`

```
div[data-role="content"].absolute_content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 44px;
        padding: 0px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: 4px;
        margin-right:4px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px gray;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Still having this issue have anybody encountred this issue?
thank you for helping me in adavance.

Comment: Are you sure it's you content div and not some wrapper of some sort?
JqueryMobile adds a lot of markup dynamically. Inspect the element by viewing the dom in live mode (not what you've written but what is being displayed).

Comment: I'm sorry I could'nt Inspect the page for now I'll do it tommorrow but
when I set the ui.content{margin:0px;} the padding looks ok but when I change it to 4px the padding starts to change automatically should I change it programmatically?

Comment: I tested on chrome really strange I dont get any additional element and the padding is ok !
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppgl95ql1v1qo95/no_padding.png

Comment: I would recommend that you append the map to div within content div, not directly to content div. because on orientation change, everything will look enlarged in landscape.